# unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

Tags: python, vscode, selenium, selenium-webdriver

He estado empezando a aprender automation con selenium python pero me tengo un problema al querer validar si todo lo necesario esta bien configurado.

Este es un pequeño codigo que hice para verificar que funcione todo

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'B:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.mx")
driver.save_screenshot("google.png")
image = Image.open("google.png")
image.show()
driver.close()
```

de esto me da el siguiente resultado en la terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Python\Automatizaciones> & C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe "c:/Users/UserName/Documents/Python/Automatizaciones/1 Validando_PY.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\UserName\Documents\Python\Automatizaciones\1 Validando_PY.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'B:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
PS C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Python\Automatizaciones>
```

Les agredeceria mucho si me ayudaran a hacer el troubleshooting para esto, muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Tengo Selenium 4.10.0

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir la versión de Selenium que usas?

Comment: Comparto la respuesta en inglés que explica por qué es importante saber qué versión de Selenium usas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70537951

Comment: La version que tengo de selenium es la 4.10.0

Answer (score 1):

Con *selenium 3.x* era relevante añadir la ruta del webdriver con el argumento `executable_path`:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'B:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
```

Con *selenium 4* hay que indicar la ruta en el servicio que luego emplea el driver:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path=r'B:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

También está la opción de colocar el webdriver en la ruta de búsqueda de ejecutables (variable de entorno `PATH`), con lo que selenium lo va a saber encontrar sin tener que configurar nada:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```